# Probability You Choose at least one chip of every color

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

There are 16 chips: 6 red, 7 white, and 3 blue. 4 chips are selected randomly and are not replaced once selected.

**What is the probability that at least one chip of every color is selected?**

I'm not every good at figuring out how to create an equation of probability for these "at least one of each kind" problems. Thanks for your help and kindness in advance. It is much appreciated.

Comment: @sasha can you go into a little bit more detail? I just started this Statistics course a week ago, we have never learned of that principle. We just learned the basic counting principle. This is all relatively new to me.

Answer (score 4):

Denoting the $(N_r, N_w, N_b)$ the triple of counts of each color in the sample, configurations that meet the requirements are $(2,1,1)$, $(1,2,1)$ or $(1,1,2)$.

The probability of the first configurations is 
$$
   p_1 = \frac{\binom{6}{2} \cdot \binom{7}{1}\cdot \binom{3}{1}}{\binom{16}{4}} = \frac{9}{52}
$$
Compute $p_2$ and $p_3$ similarly. Since these events are disjoint the answer is 
$$
   p_1 + p_2 + p_3 = \frac{9}{20}
$$

The tuple $(N_r, N_w, N_b)$ follows [multivariate hypergeometric distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution#Multivariate_hypergeometric_distribution), and you seek evaluate 
$$
   \Pr\left(N_r > 0 \land N_w > 0 \land N_r > 0 \right)
$$

Answer (score 1):

If you get at least one chip of every color, there are 3 cases to consider:

1) 2 red, 1 white, 1 blue

2) 1 red, 2 white, 1 blue

3) 1 red, 1 white, 2 blue.

Therefore the probability is given by

$\displaystyle\frac{\binom{6}{2}(7)(3)+\binom{7}{2}(6)(3)+\binom{3}{2}(6)(7)}{\binom{16}{4}}=\frac{9}{20}$.

Comment: Can you explain the numerator of that longer fraction? More specifically the multiplied coefficients by the binomials in the numerator and their purpose. Thanks a lot.

Comment: In the first term, for example, $\binom{6}{2}$ is the number of ways to choose the 2 red chips, 7 is the number of ways to choose a white chip, and 3 is the number of choices for a blue chip.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're just learning this stuff, maybe this will help.

One thing I try to keep in mind when dealing with "at least one of" type problems:

```
    Call "p" the probability of getting NO occurrences of whatever it is (basically all the ways things can be chosen so that there are no occurrences of the target item).  

    Then (1-p) is the probability of getting is the probability of getting at least one (or more).
```

Comment: I agree with that and Have been told that strategy before, I just didn't know how to apply it in this problem since their are only 3 colors and 4 selections of the chips.